# Properties of a sequence of sums of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have encountered the following sequence of alternating sums of binomials and I am wondering whether there is a nicer way to write every element and/or are there some nice properties about it.
So, if you have any idea about it, please let me know.

First of all pick two positive natural numbers $n, r\in\mathbb{N}, 0<r<n$.
Then, for all $j$, $0\leq j\leq r$, define 
$$a_j:=\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{i}\binom{j}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}$$

Note that, using the standard convention $0!=1$, the previous formula is defined also for $j=0$.

The sequence I am interested in is the sequence of these $(a_j)$'s, varying $n, r$ and obviously $j$.
In particular at some point I will sum over $j$.

So the first terms of this sequence are
$$\begin{aligned}
a_0&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}\\
a_1&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}-\binom{n-2}{r-2}\\
a_2&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}-2\binom{n-2}{r-2}+\binom{n-3}{r-3}\\
a_3&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}-3\binom{n-2}{r-2}+3\binom{n-3}{r-3}-\binom{n-4}{r-4}\\
a_4&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}-4\binom{n-2}{r-2}+6\binom{n-3}{r-3}-4\binom{n-4}{r-4}+\binom{n-5}{r-5}\\
\ldots
\end{aligned}$$

As you can see, it is very elegant, so I think that someone already studied it, and probably it is related to some property of the Pascal's triangle.

Comment: According to Mathematica it sums to $a_j={n-1\choose r-1}{}_2F_1(-j,1-r;1-n;1)$.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that also on Wolframalpha. I was actually looking for something a bit more "simple" than an ipergeometric function, even if not in such a close form.

Comment: Take a look at Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), the sum you've got looks awfully like the sums arising in his treatment of the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Mh... I do not see this big similarity. In particular that formula (4.2.7) is a summation over the first term of the binomial (aka the total number of elements), while here i sum over the second term of the binomial (how many of them I choose) and, on the other side, it is not entirely clear to me what my "set of properties" would be here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a simplification, but a nice property: Let

$$a_{n,r,j}:=\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i\binom{j}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}\qquad0<r<n,\quad0\leq j\leq r$$

> Following recursion formula is valid:
>   $$a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}+a_{n,r,j}=a_{n+1,r+1,j}$$
>   with initial condition $a_{n,r,0}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$, $0<r<n$

\begin{align}
a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}&-a_{n+1,r+1,j}\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{j+1}(-1)^i\binom{j+1}{i}\binom{n-i}{r-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i\binom{j}{i}\binom{n-i}{r-i}\\
=&(-1)^{j+1}\binom{n-j-1}{r-j-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{j}(-1)^i\left(\binom{j+1}{i}-\binom{j}{i}\right)\binom{n-i}{r-i}\\
=&-\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i\binom{j}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}=\\
=&-a_{n,r,j}
\end{align}

> **Added 2014-04-15:** Supplement - *A generating function for $a_{n,r,j}$ with derivation of a formula*

The recursion formula $a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}-a_{n+1,r+1,j}=-a_{n,r,j}$ with $0\leq j<r\leq n$ is used to find a generating function $A(x,y,z)$ for $a_{n,r,j}$.

*Note:* Since we already know a formula for $a_{n,r,j}$ (see question above) my hope was to find an alternative, simpler formula  but this wasn't the case. Nevertheless, it was a nice (and due to miscalculations sometimes cumbersome) training in calculation to *rediscover* the formula stated above.

We use the more *natural* range $r\leq n$ instead of $r<n$ (see question above) which simplifies the calculation for the generating function.

> Following statements are valid:
>
> A generating function $A(x,y,z)$ for $a_{n,r,j}$ is given by
>   $$
> A(x,y,z)=\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}
> $$
>
> Let $a_{n,r,j}$ be the coefficient of $x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}$ of $A(x,y,z)$ then
>   $$a_{n,r,j}=[x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}]A(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{k}\binom{j}{k}\binom{n-k-1}{r-k-1}\qquad0\leq j<r\leq n$$

Let 
$$A(x,y,z):=\sum_{n \geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n,r,j}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}$$ be the generating function for $a_{n,r,j}$ with $0\leq j<r\leq n$. According to the recursion formula above we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 1}&\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}
-\sum_{n \geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}\\
&=-\sum_{n \geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n,r,j}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}\\
\end{align*}

The RHS is simply: $-A(x,y,z)$. To calculate the LHS we split the task into two parts.

> First term of LHS: $\sum_{n \geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 1}&\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j+1}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{r-1}a_{n,r,j}x^{j-1}y^{r-1}z^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}a_{n,r,0}y^{r}z^{n}
-\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n,1,0}yz^{n}-a_{1,1,0}yz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}y^{r}z^{n}
-\sum_{n\geq 2}yz^{n}-yz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}y^{r+1}z^{n+1}
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1-z\right)-yz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}\left(A(x,y,z)-y\sum_{n\geq 1}z^{n+1}\left((1+y)^{n}-1\right)
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}\left(A(x,y,z)-yz\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}-1\right)+yz\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{xyz}\left(y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{xyz}A(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}\right)
\end{align*}

> Second term of LHS: $\sum_{n \geq 1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 1}&\sum_{r=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_{n+1,r+1,j}x^{j}y^{r}z^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r-2}a_{n,r,j}x^{j}y^{r-1}z^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}a_{n,r,r-1}x^{r-1}y^{r}z^{n}
-\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n,1,0}yz^{n}-a_{1,1,0}yz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{i}\binom{r-1}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}x^{r-1}y^{r}z^{n}\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{yz}\left(-\sum_{n\geq 2}yz^{n}-yz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{r=2}^{n}\binom{n-r}{r-1}x^{r-1}y^{r}z^{n}
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1-z\right)-yz\right)\tag{*}\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-\sum_{r\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq r+1}\binom{n-r-1}{r}x^{r}y^{r+1}z^{n}
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-y\sum_{r\geq 1}(xy)^r\sum_{n\geq 2}\binom{n-2}{r}z^{n+r-1}
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-yz\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n\sum_{r\geq 1}\binom{n}{r}(xyz)^r
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-yz\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n\left((1+xyz)^n-1\right)
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}\left(A(x,y,z)-yz\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+xyz)z}-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
-y\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{yz}A(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{1-(1+xyz)z}
\end{align*}

*Note:* In line $(*)$ we used the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{i}\binom{r-1}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}=\binom{n-r}{r-1}$ which can be shown e.g. by induction.

Putting all together gives an *intermediate result* for $A(x,y,z)$:
\begin{align*}
-A(x,y,z)&=\frac{1}{xyz}A(x,y,z)-\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}\right)-\frac{1}{yz}A(x,y,z)\\
&+\frac{1}{1-(1+xyz)z}\\
-xyzA(x,y,z)&=A(x,y,z)-\frac{yz}{1-(1+y)z}-xA(x,y,z)\\
&+\frac{xyz}{1-(1+xyz)z}\\
A(x,y,z)(1-x+xyz)&=\frac{yz}{1-(1+y)z}-\frac{xyz}{1-(1+xyz)z}\\
A(x,y,z)&=\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}-\frac{x}{1-(1+xyz)z}\right)
\end{align*}

> *Intermediate result* for the generating function $A(x,y,z)$:
>   $$A(x,y,z)=\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\left(\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}-\frac{x}{1-(1+xyz)z}\right)$$
>   *Note:* The generating function $A(x,y,z)$ can be simplified. We will see shortly that the *rightmost term is not needed* for the generating function of the coefficients $a_{n,r,j}$ *within the range* $0\leq j<r\leq n$.

Now we calculate $[z^n]A(x,y,z)$, the coefficient of $z^n$ from $A(x,y,z)$.

> Calculation of $[z^n]A(x,y,z)$
>
> In order to do so we split the task into two parts according to the two terms.
>
> First term of $A(x,y,z)$:

\begin{align*}
[z^n]&\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}\\
&=y[z^{n-1}]\sum_{t\geq 0}x^t(1-yz)^t\sum_{u\geq 0}(1+y)^{u}z^u\\
&=y[z^{n-1}]\sum_{t\geq 0}x^t\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-yz)^k\sum_{u\geq 0}z^u\sum_{l=0}^{u}\binom{u}{l}y^l\\
&=y[z^{n-1}]\sum_{k\geq 0}(-yz)^k\sum_{t\geq k}\binom{t}{k}x^t\sum_{u\geq 0}z^u\sum_{l=0}^{u}\binom{u}{l}y^l\\
&=y[z^{n-1}]\sum_{k\geq 0}(-yz)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t+k}\sum_{u\geq 0}z^u\sum_{l=0}^{u}\binom{u}{l}y^l\\
&=y\sum_{k\geq 0}^{n-1}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}[z^{n-1-k}]\sum_{u\geq 0}z^u\sum_{l=0}^{u}\binom{u}{l}y^l\\
&=y\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k}{l}y^l
\end{align*}

> Second term of $A(x,y,z)$:

\begin{align*}
[z^n]&\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\frac{x}{1-(1+xyz)z}\\
&=xy[z^{n-1}]\sum_{t\geq 0}x^t(1-yz)^t\sum_{u\geq 0}(1+xyz)^{u}z^u\\
&=xy[z^{n-1}]\sum_{t\geq 0}x^t\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-yz)^k\sum_{u\geq 0}z^u\sum_{l=0}^{u}\binom{u}{l}(xyz)^l\\
&=xy[z^{n-1}]\sum_{k\geq 0}(-yz)^k\sum_{t\geq k}\binom{t}{k}x^t\sum_{l\geq 0}(xyz)^l\sum_{u\geq l}\binom{u}{l}z^u\\
&=xy[z^{n-1}]\sum_{k\geq 0}(-yz)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t+k}\sum_{l\geq 0}(xyz)^l\sum_{u\geq 0}\binom{u+l}{l}z^{u+l}\\
&=xy\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}[z^{n-1-k}]\sum_{l\geq 0}(xyz^2)^l\sum_{u\geq 0}\binom{u+l}{l}z^{u}\\
&=xy\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}(xy)^l[z^{n-1-k-2l}]\sum_{u\geq 0}\binom{u+l}{l}z^{u}\\
&=xy\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k-l}{l}(xy)^l
\end{align*}

Putting all together gives:

> \begin{align*}
> [z^n]A(x,y,z)&=y\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k}{l}y^l\\
> &-xy\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k-l}{l}(xy)^l
> \end{align*}

Now we calculate the coefficients of $y^{r}z^{n}$ from $A(x,y,z)$

> Calculation of $[y^rz^n]A(x,y,z)$

\begin{align*}
[y^rz^n]&A(x,y,z)=\\
&[y^{r-1}]\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k}{l}y^l\\
&-[y^{r-1}]x\sum_{k\geq 0}(-xy)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k-l}{l}(xy)^l\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}^{r-1}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}[y^{r-1-k}]\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k}{l}y^l\\
&-x\sum_{k\geq 0}^{r-1}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}[y^{r-1-k}]\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n-1-k-l}{l}(xy)^l\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}\\
&-x\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\binom{n-r}{r-1-k}x^{r-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\\
&-x^{r}\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{n-r}{r-1-k}(-1)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}
\end{align*}

*Note:* Observe that the second summand contains only terms with powers of $x$ *greater than or equal to* $r$. This means, that it does not contribute to the coefficients $a_{n,r,j}$ we are interested in. So, we can conclude that $A(x,y,z)$ simplifies to:

> A generating function $A(x,y,z)$ of $a_{n,r,j}$ is given by
>   $$A(x,y,z)=\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}$$

Finally:

> The coefficient $[x^jy^rz^n]A(x,y,z)$

For $0\leq j<r$ we get:

\begin{align*}
[x^jy^rz^n]&A(x,y,z)\\
&=[x^j]\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}(-x)^k\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}(-1)^k[x^{j-k}]\sum_{t\geq 0}\binom{t+k}{k}x^{t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^k\binom{j}{k}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}
\end{align*}

So, we have *rediscovered* the formula from above:

> The coefficients $a_{n,r,j}$ of the generating function
>
> $$A(x,y,z)=\frac{yz}{1-x(1-yz)}\frac{1}{1-(1+y)z}$$
>
> fulfill:
>   $$a_{n,r,j}=\sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^k\binom{j}{k}\binom{n-1-k}{r-1-k}\qquad0\leq j<r\leq n$$

Comment: This is very nice indeed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplification: The following formula is valid.

> $$\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^i\binom{j}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}=\binom{n-j-1}{r-1}\qquad\qquad0<r<n,\quad0\leq j\leq r$$

Proof by induction: Let $j=0$ then $LHS=RHS=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$. Now assume the formula is valid for $j=k$.

Induction Step: $j \rightarrow k+1$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}&(-1)^i\binom{k+1}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}\\
&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{k+1}{i}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}+(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-k-2}{r-k-2}\\
&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^i\left(\binom{k}{i}+\binom{k}{i-1}\right)\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-k-2}{r-k-2}\\
&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\left(\binom{n-k-1}{r-1}-\binom{n-1}{r-1}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i-1}\binom{n-i-1}{r-i-1}\\
&\qquad+(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-k-2}{r-k-2}\qquad\qquad(\star)\\
&=\binom{n-k-1}{r-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-i-2}{r-i-2}\\
&=\binom{n-k-1}{r-1}-\binom{n-k-2}{r-2}\qquad\qquad(\star)\\
&=\binom{n-(k+1)-1}{r-1}
\end{align}
with induction hypothesis used in $(\star)$