# upper bounding alternating binomial sums

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

So we know that
$\large\sum_\limits{i=0}^t\dbinom{m}{i}\dbinom{n-m}{t-i}=\dbinom{n}{t}$ by a simple counting argument.

Now is there any bound on the quantity $\large\sum_\limits{i=0}^t(-1)^i\dbinom{m}{i}\dbinom{n-m}{t-i}$?

Can we show any non trivial upper bound on this quantity other than $\dbinom{n}{t}$?

Comment: isn't it rather $\sum_{i=0}^t\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{t-i}=\binom{n}{t}$?

Comment: Sorry my bad! ur right

Comment: you should look at the method used in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618417/prove-that-sum-k-0m-dbinomnk-dbinomn-km-k-2m-dbinomnm-for/1620874#1620874 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745051/properties-of-a-sequence-of-sums-of-binomials/750615#750615

Comment: since $\sum_{i=0}^t(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{t-i}=\binom{n}{t} $ when $m=0$, any sharper bound should involve $n$, $t$ and $m$

Comment: It is the coefficient of $x^t$ in $(1-x)^m(1+x)^{n-m}$. In particular, when $n=2m$, it is zero when $t$ is  odd. Not sure how that gives us any bound.

Comment: This may be  a formalized approach. Wolfram Alpha will give immediately
$
{n-m \choose t}  \quad  {_2{F_1}}(-m, -t, -m+n-t+1, -1)
$
and one may use properties of the hypergeometric function ${_2{F_1}}$ to arrive at bounds, e.g. use the Euler integral form.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is the sign-alternating analogue of the Chu-Vandermonde convolution.

While I haven't proved that there is no closed formula, there is an interesting statement in the 1992 article by Andersen and Larsen,
[Combinatorial Summation Identities](https://books.google.de/books?id=qZNcOygYKL0C&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=vandermonde%20convolution%20alternating%20signs&source=bl&ots=B1Vk5xLxx2&sig=XoJazAEhkc98-yE2ylejVfGw_Ys&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU-8DAq5vPAhUB1hoKHQxvCvAQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=vandermonde%20convolution%20alternating%20signs&f=false). The authors say that "the sign-alternating analogue [...] of the Chu-Vandermonde convolution is hardly known". For 3 special cases, they give the formulae by Kummer.

In his 2006 book ["Summa Summarum"](http://www.math.ku.dk/~mel/larsen.pdf), Larsen doesn't state new results either, so the 1992 quote may still hold.