# Trying to solve the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{t}(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{t-i}=0 $ for non-negative integers $m,n,t$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations

While considering a previous unanswered [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652036/upper-bounding-alternating-binomial-sums), I started looking for the non-negative integer solutions $ m,n,t  , (n\ge m)$ to the equation:

> $$ S(m,n,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{t}(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{t-i}=0 $$

The following results are quite easy to establish:

$S(m,0,t)=0$  ($m>0$)

$S(m,n,t)=0  \Leftarrow n<t$

$S(m,2m,t)=0  \Leftarrow  t$ is odd

$S(m,2t,t)=0  \Leftarrow  m$ is odd

Let us consider the above solutions as trivial solutions.

$S(m,n,n)=(-1)^m \neq 0 $

$S(0,0,t)=1$

$S(m,n,0)=1$

$S(0,n,t)=\binom{n}{t}\neq 0 $

$S(n,n,t)=(-1)^t\binom{n}{t} \neq 0 $

$S(m,2m,t)=(-1)^\frac{t}{2}  {m \choose \frac{t}{2}} \neq 0 \Leftarrow  t$ is even

Let $n>t$ and  $n>m$

$S(m,n,t)=(-1)^t S(n-m,n,t)=(-1)^m S(m,n,n-t)$

$S(m,n,t)=0 \iff S(n-m,n,t)=0 \iff S(m,n,n-t)=0$

$t!(n-t)!S(m,n,t)=m!(n-m)! S(t,n,m)$

$S(m,n,t)=0 \iff S(t,n,m)=0$

Then, it is enough to look for non-trivial solutions such that $t<\frac{n}{2}$ or $m<\frac{n}{2}$, other non-trivial solutions being obtained with the above identities.

For each solution $n(m,t)$ with $t\le m\lt\frac{n}{2}$, there exist 3 others solutions: $n(t,m)$, $n(n-m,n-t)$ and $n(n-t,n-m)$.

I have found the following four polynomial families of non-trivial solutions:

> $$ m(k) = 4 k - 1 , n(k) = 8 k + 1, t(k) = 2 k$$
>   $$ m(k)= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}, n(k) = k^2 + 4 k + 4, t(k) = 2$$
>   $$ m(k) = \frac{(k+1)(3k+2)}{2}, n(k) = 3 k^2 + 8 k + 6, t(k) = 3$$
>   $$ m(k) = \frac{(k+1)(3k+4)}{2}, n(k) = 3 k^2 + 10 k + 9, t(k) = 3$$

and the corresponding symetric families according to the above identies.

By numerical observation, the other non-trivial  solutions look more sporadic.

**Illustration:** This is a plot of the $m,n<131$ for which there exists $t<n+m$ such that $m,n,t$ is a non-trivial solution to the equation $ S(m,n+m,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{t}(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{t-i}=0 $

The green, blue and black dots correspond to the above polynomial families of solutions, and the red dots are for the other non trivial solutions.

[image]

The red dots look more sporadic but there are some patterns too. Most of them belong to one of the following nine "exponential" families of solutions  $m(k),n(k),t(k)$ which are defined by second order linear recurrences. (And the corresponding associated families according to the above symetries).

> $$m(k)=6m(k-1)-m(k-2)+10$$ $$ t(k)=6t(k-1)-t(k-2)+2$$
>   $$n(k)=2m(k)+4$$   $$m(0)=-2,m(1)=-1\ \  \ t(0)=0,t(1)=0$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=18m(k-1)-m(k-2)+48$$ $$ t(k)=18t(k-1)-t(k-2)+8$$
>   $$n(k)=2m(k)+5$$   $$m(0)=2,m(1)=-2\ \  \ t(0)=6,t(1)=0$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=18m(k-1)-m(k-2)+48$$ $$t(k)=18t(k-1)-t(k-2)+8$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+5$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-1,m(1)=-1\ \  \ t(0)=2,t(1)=0$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=18m(k-1)-m(k-2)+48$$ $$t(k)=18t(k-1)-t(k-2)+8$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+5$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-1,m(1)=-1\ \  \ t(0)=3,t(1)=1$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=18m(k-1)-m(k-2)+48$$ $$t(k)=18t(k-1)-t(k-2)+8$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+5$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-2,m(1)=2\ \  \ t(0)=1,t(1)=3$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=14m(k-1)-m(k-2)+42$$ $$t(k)=14t(k-1)-t(k-2)+6$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+6$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-1,m(1)=-2\ \  \ t(0)=4,t(1)=0$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=14m(k-1)-m(k-2)+42$$ $$t(k)=14t(k-1)-t(k-2)+6$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+6$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-2,m(1)=-1\ \  \ t(0)=2,t(1)=0$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=6m(k-1)-m(k-2)+18$$ $$t(k)=6t(k-1)-t(k-2)+2$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+8$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-1,m(1)=-2\ \  \ t(0)=5,t(1)=1$$
>   $$ $$
>   $$m(k)=6m(k-1)-m(k-2)+18$$ $$t(k)=6t(k-1)-t(k-2)+2$$ $$ n(k)=2m(k)+8$$ 
>   $$m(0)=-2,m(1)=-1\ \  \ t(0)=3,t(1)=1$$

Question: Are there other known families (polynomial, exponential or not) of non-trivial solutions?

Here are the only solutions $n(m,t)$ , ($n \gt 2m\ge 2t$)    that I have found so far, which do not belong to any one of the above thirteen polynomial or exponential families.

> $$67 (22, 5)$$
>   $$67 (28, 5)$$
>   $$289 (133, 5)$$
>   $$345 (155, 6)$$
>   $$1029 (496, 7)$$
>   $$1521 (715, 4)$$
>   $$10882 (5292, 5)$$
>   $$15043 (7476, 4)$$ 
>   $$48324 (24013, 5)$$

Here are two of the corresponding identities:

> $$\binom{24013}{0}\binom{24311}{5}-\binom{24013}{1}\binom{24311}{4}+\binom{24013}{2}\binom{24311}{3}-\binom{24013}{3}\binom{24311}{2}+\binom{24013}{4}\binom{24311}{1}-\binom{24013}{5}\binom{24311}{0} =0 $$
>   $$\binom{496}{0}\binom{533}{7}-\binom{496}{1}\binom{533}{6}+\binom{496}{2}\binom{533}{5}-\binom{496}{3}\binom{533}{4}+\binom{496}{4}\binom{533}{3}-\binom{496}{5}\binom{533}{2}+\binom{496}{6}\binom{533}{1}-\binom{496}{7}\binom{533}{0}=0$$

but other similar 'sporadic' identies are very difficult to find as they correspond to solutions to polynomial Diophantine equations of high order. I am wondering whether they even exist. Any idea about that?

I believe that for a given $t$, there are only a finite number of such $n(m,t)$.

For $t=4$, the above list is complete.

For $t=5$, the above list would be complete, if it can be shown that the set of solutions $x$ to the equation:
$$2 (x^2 - 4) (x^2 - 1) = 45 (y^2 - 1)$$ is $$\{1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 23, 298\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the polynomial which you call $S(m,n,t)$ are in fact Krawtchouk polynomials $K^n_t(m)$ i.e. the coefficient of $x^t$ in the polynomial $(1-x)^m (1+x)^{n-m}$ and there is a long list of papers that study the zeros of these polynomials and I do not think it has been fully characterized in terms of all parameters. We do know the behavior of the first  root and so on though. Look at, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03321065#/page-1 and references therein.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is answering the reference request. The studies about the zeros do not seem to talk about the integer zeros, do they?  I have added an illustration in my initial post, in order to make the problem more visual.

Comment: I do think there is some form of bound known about the first integral zero for example of the Krawtchouk polynomials though, in the sense we know that the first root is $n\cdot 1/2-\sqrt{s/n(1-s/n)}+o(n)$. Similarly i believe some references might have looked at other integral solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the sequence that you give in the OEIS 
$$
9,16,17,22,25,33,34,36,41,49,57,64,65,66,67,73,81,86,89,...
$$
in the context of multiple photon interference on an ideal 50:50 beamsplitter. In this context, these are the photon numbers $N$, where there are non-trivial suppression events (complete destructive interference, where the input state is not the symmetric $\left| m=N/2\right\rangle := \left|N/2,N/2 \right\rangle$ state) and the corresponding equation is:

$$
Q^{(N)}_{n,m}=\sum_{k=0}^{\min(n,m)} \frac{(N-k)!}{k!(n-k)!(m-k)!} \left( -\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-k}=0.
$$

The quantity $Q^{(N)}_{n,m}$ is directly related to the Jacobi Polynomials $P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(x)$, with $\alpha=m-n$, $\beta=N-m-n$ and $x=0$. By associating $(m,n,t) \leftrightarrow (m,N,n)$, $S$ and $Q$ vanish simultaneously. I don't know whether this is helpful, but maybe you get some idea starting from this expression?
And just out of interest: Where and how did you encounter this equation?