# Closed form for weighted sum involving product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed form for the following expression?$$\sum_iA^i \binom{K-j}{L-i}\binom{j}{i}$$

If $A=1$ this is equal to $\binom{K}{L}$ by Vandermonde's identity.  Further, I know that the sum in question is equal to the coefficient of $x^L$ in $(1+x)^{K-j}(1+Ax)^j$.  However, I do not see how to come up with a closed form.

Comment: What are $j,K,L$? What are the bounds of the summation?

Comment: @ClementC.: You can treat the bounds as $-\infty$ and $\infty$: only finitely many terms are non-zero. If you really want bounds, make them $0$ and $\min\{j,L\}$.

Comment: I see -- thanks.

Comment: Could you say why you are interested by a closed form here ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the expression arose when studying the equivariant cohomology of affine Grassmanians.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand "affine grassmannians" but "equivariant cohomology" in these manifolds remains rather mysterious for me.

Comment: the case $A=-1$ is considered in these questions : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1652036 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1664420     Apparently, there is no easy closed form.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> For the purpose of the example, I'll assume $\ds{\ell = 0,1,\ldots,j}$:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{\ell = 0}^{j}A^{\ell}{K - j \choose L - \ell}{j \choose \ell} =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{j}A^{\ell}{j \choose \ell}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{K - j} \over z^{L - \ell + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{K - j \choose L - \ell}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{K - j} \over z^{L + 1}}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{j}{j \choose \ell}\pars{Az}^{\ell}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\pars{1 + z}^{K - j}\,\,\pars{1 + Az}^{\,j} \over z^{L + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\,\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:2px dotted navy]{\ds{\bracks{z^{L}}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{K - j}\,\,\pars{1 + Az}^{\, j}}}}
\end{align}

> which agrees with the claimed OP solution.

CAS yields the cumbersome answer:
$$
A^{L}{j \choose L}\
{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{j - K,-L;j - L + 1;{1 \over A}}
$$